# NodeJS Parallesim Understanding

Tags: performance, node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Consider the following examples: (assume express is available)

**Example 1:**

```
app.get("/a", function(res){
    // Some-Blocking function for 10 seconds
    res.send("done");
});

app.get("/b", function(res){
    res.send("done");
});
```

In this example, if /a is requested first, then 1 seconds later /b; /b is not handled until /a is completed? If it is one thread, it should be. So what is the way of eliminating this issue?

**Example 2:**

```
app.get("/a", function(res){
    // Some-Library-Database function
    db.find({"user.id" : 5}, function(data){
        res.send(data);
    });
});


app.get("/b", function(res){
    res.send("done");
});
```

Again, /a is requested so it enters the function, calls db.find, so when db.find is complete, the callback executes res.send(data) of A. So, we can respond /b without waiting /a request, right? (Correct me if I'm wrong)

So, how can we achieve the Example 2 in Example 1 too? Can we make that blocking function to run async too? Or is DB doing IO (sending commands over TCP to server etc.) makes the function asynchronous? I mean, is the only thing async in nodejs ,s IO? If a large computation is needed, do we have to make an IO request?

I am trying to learn and build according to the concepts. I have read [NodeJS is cancer](http://teddziuba.com/2011/10/node-js-is-cancer.html) post to read criticism about Node, not sure if he is just trolling or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. put "Some-Blocking function for 10 seconds" into block.js
2. call [child_process.fork](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) at the beginning of your main code ('app.js' )
3. add 'message' event handler in block.js, put your blocking code there
4. call child as b.send(arguments), read reply in `b.on('message', function(reply) {...}});`

This way you have everything processed sequentially in your blocking handler, and still allowing clients not using 'blocking' code to be processed in parent 'app.js'

edit: updated docs link

Comment: btw, if you have something "blocking for 10 seconds" it either due blocking IO (and most probably you have non-blocking node alternative) or CPU bound task (and probably it's worth to be rewritten in something like C/C++)

Comment: the link seems to be broken